# Sigma algebra generated by integral of random process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Suppose that we are given a random process $(X_t)_{0 \le t \le T}$ on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ such that the integral $Y(\omega) = \int_0^T X_s(\omega) ds$ makes sense for all $\omega\in\Omega$.

1. What can we say about the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $Y$?
   It would make sense for $Y$ to be measurable with respect to $\mathcal F_T = \sigma(X_t : 0 \le t \le T)$, but we cannot expect the converse inclusion since we don't even have $\sigma(X, Y) \subseteq \sigma(X + Y)$ in general, i.e., it fails for simple processes. But in general you would expect that $Y$ "has something to do with" the values of $X_t$ up to $T$.
2. In particular, what can we say about $X$ if we suppose that $Y$ is $\sigma(X_T)$-measurable? It feels like such a process should satisfy something like $\mathcal F_t = \sigma(X_T)$ for all $t$, but I cannot prove this and maybe the setting is too general.

Comment: Are we assuming anything about $X$ here?  For example, $X$ being adapted to some filtration, or being a predictable process?

Comment: In the context which lead me to this question, $X$ is given by an Ito integral $X_t = \int_0^t f(s) dB_s$ for a deterministic integrand $f$ and a Brownian motion $B$. So, yes, $X$ can be assumed to be predictable and/or adapted to the filtration generated by the increments of $B$ if this helps/is necessary.